# Is there a way to define import alias for go generated code from proto files

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, protoc

I am import two different proto files in my current proto file as below

```
import "author/message/name.proto"
import "reader/message/details.proto"
```

in name.proto I have `go_package = "author/message"` and in details.proto I have `go_package = "reader/message"` because of which when pb.go is generated import alias is showing as below

```
message1 "author/message"

message2 "reader/message"
```

I am trying to find a way where i can name alias like authormsg and readermsg respectively during pb.go generation. I have checked documentation but couldnt find anyway to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the explicit Go package name like this:

- `name.proto`: `option go_package="author/message;authormsg"`
- `details.proto`: `option go_package="reader/message;readermsg"`

Means you add the package name separated with a semicolon (`;`) after the import path.

Note:

> This usage is discouraged since the package name will be derived by default from the import path in a reasonable manner.
> [Protocol Buffers documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/go-generated#package)

Comment: I have tried this solution but still in pb.go it is generating package alias names as message1 & message2. Even though I have added 
`option go_package="author/message;authormsg"`
`option go_package="reader/message;readermsg"`

Comment: @BhanuReddy Ah, you don't mean the Go package name, e.g. `package authormsg` in `name.pb.go`. 

Instead do you want that _inside_ your `pb.go` there's no `import message1 "author/message"`? 

That might be when your `name.pb.go` really resides in path `author/message` and `protoc-gen-go` assumes the [Go's convention import-path base == package-name](https://blog.golang.org/package-names#TOC_4.) and doesn't check the real `package` inside the `pb.go`.

However, why do you care about this? When using the generated code, you don't see it at all.

Comment: yeah in import statement package alias is not happening like 
import ( MY_NAME "reader/message" ) since there are multiple package imports like below 
`import( 
message1 "reader/message" 
message2 "writer/message" 
message3 "fastreader/message" 
message4 "fastwriter/message" )` 
The package alias names message1 ... message4 while reading code it is getting difficult so wanted to make it more readable by generating pb.go like below `import( 
reader "reader/message" 
writer "writer/message" 
fastreader "fastreader/message" 
fastwriter "fastwriter/message" )`